# After upgrading to windows 10, Android studio will not compile

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-10

Fellow developers,

After upgrading to `windows 10`, android studio will not compile my project. My app is live and I can do nothing. Please help.

Gradle error:

```
Possible causes could be:  
    - you are using Gradle version where the method is absent 
    - you didn't apply Gradle plugin which provides the method
    - or there is a mistake in a build script
```

Similar posts do not solve my problem.

Even backups will not compile.

My keys are safe. Do I need to rebuild from scratch?

I am back to `8.1` now, still no solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please inform the Android Studio and gradle versions?

Comment: Android Studio (Beta) 0.8.9
Gradle Version 2.4
Android Plugin Version 1.2.3

Comment: Why are you using beta version of Android Studio?  Is this a special version for Windows 10??  I believe current version of Android Studio is 1.3.

Comment: I have downloaded studio from the official site and started development 8 months ago. Android studio was working perfectly and it never occurred to me to check the version; update has always been automatic (stable channel). After publishing the app 2 days ago, decided to upgrade to win10. Now I have no way to continue my project unless I remake the entire app. Just to let you know, I am self-taught and manage the app completely by myself. So this is a real set back for me. 

Update: Reinstalled Android Studio: same problem.!

I should NEVER have gotten into development I guess.!

Answer (score 3):

After days of searching, the answer was simple. I had to change the pro Guard settings. Lesson learned: update studio BEFORE upgrading to Windows 10 and make sure your Studio project is NOT on the desktop (or similar places that may be non-standard). Hope this helps someone..